# Entity Framework does not read FK Relationships, LINQ To SQL Does

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, entity-framework

I am trying to create an Entity Model from a database.  When I add the tables EF does not read my existing FK constraints.  If I make a Linq to SQL file in the same project and add the same tables it reads the constraints without issue.

Whats the deal?

Comment: Do your FK constraints use primary keys?

Comment: Yes, all of my keys are properly defined in SQL as keys (EDM reads those fine, even puts the little key icon on them).  EDM doesn't read the FK constraints between the keys though.

Comment: Are you adding tables or views? EF is not smart enough to use keys through views. It only works with tables.

Comment: I am only adding tables, no views involved.

Comment: What exactly is missing in your model - just properties for FKs or whole relations?

Comment: All relations are missing in the model.  I can add them by hand but with the total number of tables being muhc larger then four I'd just prefer they add themselves.

Comment: Have you tried it with EF5 on .NET Framework 4.5?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recently I had the same issue - I am not sure why, but somehow the Entity Framework conflicts with some non-clustered indexes.

*Similar situation:*

> http://blog.degree.no/2012/09/missing-relations-in-entityframework-model-when-generating-from-database/

You can try removing your indexes, regenerate your model, add the indexes again and update the regenerated model - it worked for me.

Comment: Thanks for the information!  Unfortunately I don't have the ability to change the database design, but this sounds like the probable cause based on the way my indexes are setup.  Maybe I'll get the opportunity to make changes to the DB design in the future and utilize your answer.